# How to use Spring batch CompositeItemWriter with different data and having two JdbcBatchItemWritter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Need a solution to write a compositer writer with two JdbcBatchItemWriter and also differ data sets

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example in [spring-batch-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#composite-itemwriter-sample) repository. [This sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/compositeItemWriterSampleJob.xml) shows how to use a composite `item writer` with two flat file item writers, but you can adapt it with two jdbc batch `item writers`.